# LDAP groups not applying to filesystem permissions

Tags: ldap, nss

System is ArchLinux, and I'm using nss-pam-ldapd (0.8.13-4) to connect myself to ldap.

Relevant configuration files:

- [/etc/nsswitch.conf](https://gist.github.com/dkowis/7104646)
- [/etc/nslcd.conf](https://gist.github.com/dkowis/7103471)

I've got my users and some groups in LDAP:

```
[root@kain tmp]# getent group
<localgroups snipped>
dkowis:*:10000:
mp3s:*:15000:rkowis,dkowis
music:*:15002:rkowis,dkowis
video:*:15003:transmission,rkowis,dkowis,sickbeard
software:*:15004:rkowis,dkowis
pictures:*:15005:rkowis,dkowis
budget:*:15006:rkowis,dkowis
rkowis:*:10001:
```

And I have some directories that are setgid `video` so that the video group stays, and they're configured g=rwx so that members of the `video` group can write to them:

```
[root@kain video]# ls -ld /srv/video
drwxrwxr-x 8 root video 208 Oct 19 20:49 /srv/video
```

However, members of that group, say `dkowis` cannot write into that directory:

```
[root@kain video]# groups dkowis
mp3s music video software pictures dkowis
```

Total number of groups that dkowis is in is like 7, I redacted a few here.

```
[dkowis@kain wat]$ cd /srv/video
[dkowis@kain video]$ touch something
touch: cannot touch 'something': Permission denied

[dkowis@kain video]$ groups
dkowis mp3s music video software pictures
```

I'm at a loss as to why my groups show up in `getent groups`, but my filesystem permissions are not being respected. I've tried making a new directory in `/tmp` and setting it's group permissions to rwx, and then trying to write a file in there, it doesn't work. The only time it does work is if I open it wide up allowing o=rwx. That's obviously not what I want, and I'm not able to figure out what my missing piece is.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: stopping nscd had no effect either. It doesn't appear to be a caching problem.

EDIT: a bit of expirementing:

Locally defined groups work just fine, this seem to only affect LDAP groups, added to /etc/group:

```
test:x:15007:dkowis
mkdir /tmp/wat
chgrp test /tmp/wat
chmod g+rws /tmp/wat
su - dkowis
cd /tmp/wat
touch something
[dkowis@kain wat]$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwsr-x 2 root   test  60 Oct 22 11:26 .
drwxrwxrwt 8 root   root 160 Oct 22 11:26 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 dkowis test   0 Oct 22 11:26 something
```

Comment: what OS are you using? Is it using sssd?

Comment: This is Arch Linux, and I'm using nss-pam-ldapd, as specified.

Comment: what is in /etc/nslcd.conf? and also when you are trying to touch that file in the folder what secure.log/auth.log shows?

Comment: Nothing shows up in /var/log/secure, /etc/nslcd.conf: https://gist.github.com/dkowis/7103471

Comment: k and nsswitch.conf?

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to add that, heh. https://gist.github.com/dkowis/7104646 And I'll put it in the question proper.

Comment: Dunno, can you try to set the user and group cache time to something low in /etc/nscd.conf.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11161/discussion-between-beepdog-and-danila-ladner)

Comment: Sure, create a room

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into a namespace collision.

By default `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is configured to look first at files then at external sources.
`group: files ldap`.

This means that the video group from `/etc/group` will match before the video group in ldap. This can be seen by running `getent group video`.

Comment: in my case, when i was using chmod it was using the group with the lowest id, which wasnt matching the groupid in ldap